# How to turn off remote debugging in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I got the project written in WPF + C# in VS2010 and when i start it by pressing F5 (but not Ctrl-F5, that works normal), the program itself starts lagging and task manager shows that in High Priority msvsmon.exe consumes almost all the CPU. But it happens when i press buttons, type in textboxes and so on.

So how to turn it off?

Comment: You are describing normal debugging, not remote debugging.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Debug without debugging? Just run the program? What exactly?

Comment: Hmmm, description of msvsmon.exe says it is remote debugging manager. i might be wrong. but WPF's UI is still very laggy (by the way, on another machine it works fine).

Comment: Have you set a remote machine in the Debug tab of the project properties?

Comment: @Richard Nope I have not

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The remote debugger is also used in non-remote debugging scenarios.  When your program runs in 64-bit mode for example.  VS is a 32-bit program, it uses the remote debugger to debug the program in that case.

You can avoid it by forcing your program to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, change the Platform target setting to x86.  Also enables Edit and Continue, nice.

Seeing msvsmon.exe consuming so much cpu cycles is unhealthy of course.  Hard to guess what might cause it.  Check for a storm of handled exceptions, you'll see their first-chance notification in the Output window.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox to make the debugger stop on them.  But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

In your app or web.config file disable it!

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Remote.Disable"
      value="1" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```